# Pass a parameter from one batch file to another batch file

Tags: sql, batch-file, database-backups

I have two batch files.

1. First extracts date from and creates folder in \YEAR\MONTH\DATE format.

   `@echo off
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   :: Extract date fields
       for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (
           set v1=%%i& set v2=%%j& set v3=%%k
           if "%%i:~0,1%%" gtr "9" (set v1=%%j& set v2=%%k& set v3=%%l)
           for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo.^|date') do (
           set %%m=!v1!& set %%n=!v2!& set %%o=!v3!    ))</br>
   :: Final set for language independency
   set year=%yy%%aa%
   set month=%mm%
   set day=%dd%
   :: Make Dir
   set root=f:\
   ::Create folder of today's date
   if exist %root% goto L2
   goto L3
   :L2
   if not exist %root%\%year%  md %root%\%year%
   :L3
   if exist %root%\%year%\%month% goto L5
   :L4
   if not exist %root%\%year%\%month%  md %root%\%year%\%month%
   :L5
   md %root%\%year%\%month%\%day%
   :: Detete folder older than '3' days
   forfiles /p "%root%%year%\%month%" /s /d -3 /c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
   echo.
   pause`
2. creates a backup of database

   `echo off
   cls
   echo -- BACKUP DATABASE --
   ::set db name
   set DATABASENAME='db_name'
   :: set path and format
   set BACKUPFILENAME='path\%DATABASENAME%.bak'
   :: set server name
   set SERVERNAME='server name'
   echo.
   ::backup execution
   sqlcmd -S %SERVERNAME% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DATABASENAME%] TO DISK = N'%BACKUPFILENAME%' WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'%DATABASENAME% backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT"
   echo.`

Now I want to call the second batch file from first and also pass the parameters like root, year, month, date from first to second.
I've tried both codes individually and its working perfectly. How can I pass the parameters. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call second batch from first one, something like

```
call backupDP.cmd
```

both files share the same environment, so, both see the same variables. No need to pass anything, the second batch already has all the data.

Comment: Thanks @MC ND. But will the second file understand what root, year, month, date means

Comment: @vrun, i know i will not say anything new, but batch files are programs. Your question and my answer were about data interchange. It is the programmer task to code the program to make use of the data or understand what it means. Sorry, i don't have enough information to know how it will be used.